# wx.Radiobox.SetBackgroundColour("pink") won't change the color of RadioButton until mouse pass by

Tags: python, wxpython

I've built a `wx.Dialog`, with some `wx.Radiobox` need to validate. If user doesn't make a choice, the validator wouldn't return `True` and popup a `wx.MessageBox` tells user that you should choose something. Meanwhile, the background color should have changed to pink.

The problem here is when using `RadioBox.SetBackgroundColour("pink")`, the Background color of  RadioBox's label text changed to pink, which is perfectly normal, but the background color for RadioButton's label text won't change until mouse pass by.

I'm wondering why this and how to fix it. I've looked up in official docs and googled, but find nothing. Anyone have idea?

The platform is win8.1x64 and python 2.7.3 and wxpython 2.8.12.1. For using Psychopy standalone package, the version of both python and wxpython are quite old.

The Dialog as follow, a quite simple one :

```
class Dlg(wx.Dialog):
    """A simple dialogue box."""

    def __init__(self):
        global app
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None,-1)

        self.sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(cols=1)

    def show(self, cancelBTN=False):
        """Show a dialog with 2 RadioBox"""

        # add two RadioBox

        RadioBox1 = wx.RadioBox(self, -1, label="Wierd color", choices=["", "choice A", "choice B"], validator=RadioObjectValidator())
        RadioBox2 = wx.RadioBox(self, -1, label="Wierd color", choices=["", "choice A", "choice B"], validator=RadioObjectValidator())
        RadioBox1.ShowItem(0, show=False)  # Hide the first choice
        RadioBox2.ShowItem(0, show=False)  # Hide the first choice

        RadioBox1.GetValue = RadioBox1.GetStringSelection
        RadioBox2.GetValue = RadioBox2.GetStringSelection
        self.sizer.Add(RadioBox1, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.sizer.Add(RadioBox2, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT)

        # add buttons for OK

        self.sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK), 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        if self.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            pass
            # do something

        self.Destroy()
```

And Validator as this:

```
class RadioObjectValidator(wx.PyValidator):
    """ This validator is used to ensure that the user has entered something
        into the text object editor dialog's text field.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Standard constructor.
        """
        wx.PyValidator.__init__(self)

    def Clone(self):
        """ Standard cloner.

            Note that every validator must implement the Clone() method.
        """
        return RadioObjectValidator()

    def Validate(self, win):
        """ Validate the contents of the given RadioBox control.
        """
        RadioBox = self.GetWindow()
        choice = RadioBox.GetValue()

        if not choice:
            wx.MessageBox(u'Choose something please', u'info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
            RadioBox.SetBackgroundColour("pink")
            RadioBox.SetFocus()
            RadioBox.Refresh()
            return False
        else:
            RadioBox.SetBackgroundColour(
                wx.SystemSettings_GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW))
            RadioBox.Refresh()
            return True

    def TransferToWindow(self):
        """ Transfer data from validator to window.

            The default implementation returns False, indicating that an error
            occurred.  We simply return True, as we don't do any data transfer.
        """
        return True  # Prevent wxDialog from complaining.

    def TransferFromWindow(self):
        """ Transfer data from window to validator.

            The default implementation returns False, indicating that an error
            occurred.  We simply return True, as we don't do any data transfer.
        """
        return True  # Prevent wxDialog from complaining.
```

And simply run like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Dlg()
    test.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple "main" wrapper so we can run your code and check whether this happens 1) at all 2) on all platforms  3) What tweaking might fix.   At face value it sounds like a bug in wx.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks for concern and reminding, A simple piece code for running it added at the bottom, and hope this help

Comment: Heh - such a simple wrapper to run it, but for a person coming to help you, it's best to have that, because it can be non-trivial to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bug in wxpython2.8.12.1, and has fixed in wxpython3.0.0.0, Thanks @GreenAsJade for reminding.